# Detecting what part of screen/application window is using OpenGL?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl, quartz-graphics

I am interested in identifying which part of application is making use of OpenGL.

Take an example of Chrome where Youtube video being played in Flash (get rendered via OpenGL). I am interested in detecting only the area of application where that OpenGL activity is being done?

If the condition is that I need to be inside the application, like say to inject in Chrome, I can do that too.

Let me know if I can clarify question more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is this private API which allow you to know the surface on which opengl is rendering.

```
CG_EXTERN CGError CGSGetSurfaceBounds(CGSConnectionID, CGWindowID, CGSSurfaceID, CGRect* bounds);
```

Using this we can detect specific area of application which makes use of OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged your question as MacOS X. Then you can simply assume everything on screen being drawn using OpenGL, because OpenGL is used as the graphics backend for the whole system.

Comment: Yes you are right in a way. But I need only specific area of application which makes use of OpenGL. I have updated my question.